# discord.py-rewrite - Manipulating exceptions through cogs

Tags: discord, discord.py

So, on my main file `bot.py`, I have:

```
class Bot(commands.Bot):

    # BOT ATTRIBUTES

    class MyException(Exception):
        def __init__(self, argument):
            self.argument = argument

bot = Bot(...)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isistance(error, bot.MyException):
        await ctx.send("{} went wrong!".format(error.argument))
    else:
        print(error)
```

Now I also have a cog file, where I sometimes want to throw the `Bot().MyException` exception:

```
class Cog(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def a_command(self, ctx):
        if a_condition:
            raise self.bot.MyException("arg")
```

When I run the code, if the `a_condition` has been validated, the program raises the `MyException` exception, but the BOT do not send the desired message in the `on_command_error()` function in `bot.py`. Instead, the exception gets printed in the console and I get this error message:

```
Command raised an exception: MyException: arg
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make the BOT say the desired message in `on_command_error()` in `bot.py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands will only raise exceptions derived from `CommandError`.  When your command raises a non-`CommandError` exception, it will be wrapped in a [`CommandInvokeError`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandInvokeError):

```
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        if isinstance(error.original, bot.MyException):
            await ctx.send("{} went wrong!".format(error.argument))
            return
    print(error)
```